# Python Flask server running twice - can't figure out what is causing it to restart

Tags: python, flask

Every single time I run my python script, it reloads and thus runs the contents of the script twice.

This is a Flask application, and I have Debug=True, but I was under the impression it would only restart the server if I re-saved a file (which I'm not doing). Is it possible to change this behavior? As soon as I remove the Debug=True setting, it stops, but ideally I'd like to be able to have it on for the time being.

My basic run.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
  # DEBUG = True
)

if (__name__):
  app.run()
```

Comment: What do you mean "runs twice"? It's very hard to run on the same port. Are you sure that's what happens?

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Sorry, 'runs twice' was horrible terminology on my part. The server runs, then restarts.

Comment: I'm presuming, by "runs, then restarts", you mean that every time you modify a file and save it, the server reloads the file? If so, see my answer to prevent that.

Comment: Yup, would've said thanks, but the StackOverflow Comment Placeholder overlords told me to avoid that. But thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Where you declare `debug=True`, add the argument `use_reloader=False`.

[See the Flask API documentation on `run` for more details.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.run)

Comment: ...link is broken